# Python ImportError: cannot import name __init__.py

Tags: python, import

I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'life_table' from 'cdc_life_tables' (C:\Users\tony\OneDrive\Documents\Retirement\retirement-mc-master\cdc_life_tables\__init__.py)
```

When I try to run this (`retirement_mc.py`):

```
from cdc_life_tables import life_table
```

`__init__.py` looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from cdc_life_tables import *
```

and `cdc_life_tables.py` contains `life_table` and looks like this:

```
def life_table(state_abbrev, demographic_group):
  
    state_abbrev = state_abbrev.upper()

    try:
        state = abbrev2name[state_abbrev]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError('"{}" not a state abbreviation.'.format(state_abbrev))

    state = state.lower().replace(' ', '_')


    try:
        demographic_group = demographic_group.lower()
        if len(demographic_group) > 2:
           demographic_group = groups_long2short[demographic_group]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError('"{}" not a valid .'.format(demographic_group))
        
    s = '{}{}_{}.csv'.format(lt_dir, state, demographic_group)

    if os.path.exists(s):
        df = pd.read_csv(s)
    else:
        raise ValueError('{} not a demographic group for {}.'.format(demographic_group, state_abbrev))

    return df['qx']
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = life_table('PA', 'wf')
```

I'm using Spyder (Python 3.7)

Comment: I'm confused - are you trying to import a named function (`life_table`) from a module (`__init__.py`) that only contains a global import? What does `*` refer to here?

Comment: I'm using * to import all the variables from cdc_life_tables

Comment: Where are you trying to execute that? Is that a valid name in that module?

Comment: I think it's a valid name.  I'll add some more information above which may help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With this line:

```
from cdc_life_tables import *
```

your package is attempting to `import *` from *itself*. You need to `import *` from the `cdc_life_tables` *submodule* of the current package, most easily done with a relative import:

```
from .cdc_life_tables import *
```

Comment: Thanks, I deleted "from cdc_life_tables import *" from _init_.py and then renamed the first file in the path and then used: from life_tables.cdc_life_tables import life_table

Answer (score 0):

My `__init__.py` file looked like this

```
repo_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

giving this error on `repo_root` .

Changing to

```
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
repo_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

solved it.

Annoying that you don't get some more informative error.