# Cannot import "object" from "module" in Python

Tags: python, pip

I've been writing a Python SDK for code generated from Protobuf. I have it uploaded to Test PyPI and am able to download it by doing:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ alphausblue
```

This downloads the package to my the store associated with my conda environment, `test`. I have confirmed that the code's distribution info is located in `\anaconda3\envs\test\Lib\site-packages\alphausblue-0.1.0.dist-info` and that the code itself is located in `\anaconda3\envs\test\Lib\site-packages\alphausblue` and if I try to do any of the following, I get no error:

```
import alphausblue
import alphausblue.org
import alphausblue.org.v1
import alphausblue.org.v1 as org
from alphausblue.org.v1 import *
```

Furthermore, if I do the following:

```
import alphausblue.org.v1 as org
org
```

then the interpreter prints `<module 'alphausblue.org.v1' from '\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\alphausblue\org\v1\__init__.py'>`. Navigating to this location, I see the associated files are there. However, if I try to do:

```
org.Organization
from alphausblue.org.v1 import Organization
```

I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Organization' from 'alphausblue.org.v1' (\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\alphausblue\org\v1_*init*_.py)

I've researched this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834348/python-importerror-cannot-import-name-init-py) but this doesn't seem related. How do I fix this import error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `Organization` in `alphausblue\org\v1\__init__.py`:

```
from .org_pb2_grpc import Organization
```

Comment: So I can't just leave the `__init__.py` file in each directory empty? These files are generated so I'd like to avoid inserting custom code in them if possible

Comment: Ah sorry, this ended up being a much more stupid problem than I had originally thought.